# While loop on python not working correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm learning python through the Automate the boring stuff with python, and as I was progressing through the initial chapters, I decided to try to code something different than what the author purposes. During a toxicology class, the teacher said that a type of snails was dying up to 12% per year. So I decided to make a code to calculate that.

The code I made is this:

```
number= input('Number of individuals: ')  #tells the number of individuals in the beggining
count = 0 #tells the nuumber of generations
number=int(number)
percent=input('% of loss per generation ')  #% of individuals lost in each generation
percent=int(percent)

#while number > 1:
 #   number= number*(percent*0.01)
  #  number=round(number,-1)
   # count = count +1
    #print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number*0.1) + ' individuals')
    #if number == 1:
     #   print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')


while True:
    if number == 1:
        print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')
    if number >1:
        number= number*(percent*0.01)
        number=round(number,-1)
        count = count +1
        print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number*0.1) + ' individuals')
    if number == 0 :
        break
```

The first code that i tried to made is in comments, and I tried to make another way to try to solve my problem.

My problem is :
I want to input the number of individuals and the percentage of losses. In the end (which is 1 because the individual can't mate with itself), I want it to tell me the number of generations it took to end with the species. The problem begins when the program loops one more time than its supposed (and before i used the round() function it even loops more times) because I don't want the 0 value, and the fact that when it reaches 1 I want it to tell me how many generations it took to end with it.

I tried to look for answers but because I'm a beginner I may not know correctly the terms to do the proper search.
The way I see it, the program should be running like I wanted, but I guess I'm missing something which I'm not getting.

Comment: I think you mean to have number reduce BY the percentage, not To the percentage - try that. `number = number * (1-(percent*.01))`

Comment: Can you please provide a sample set of input and your expected results ..your requirement is not clear

Comment: @HariomSingh I want the program to ask me the number of individuals, and I'll input something like 12587392572439 and say something like 9% of losses. It should output something like the number of individuals in each generation, printing each one, and at the last, tell me how many generations it took to end.

Comment: @Alan, I tried that but it keeps looping now on for example 7 individuals. Any ideas on how to solve the new problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's discuss the code in comments, because it's a better solution, which just needs some improvements. There are two main problems in your code

1) Why do you print `number * 0.1` instead of just `number`? It shows 1 when should show 10, and I believe this is the main problem, which mislead you.

```
print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number*0.1) + ' individuals')
```

2) The following two lines must be not in the loop, because it's actually possible that you pass 1 through und will never see result message. Those lines must be placed after the loop:

```
if number == 1:
    print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')
```

Here what we have as a result:

```
number= input('Number of individuals: ')  # tells the number of individuals in the beggining
count = 0 # tells the nuumber of generations
number=int(number)
percent=input('% of loss per generation ')  # % of individuals lost in each generation
percent=int(percent) * 0.01

while number > 1:
    number = number * percent
    number = round(number)
    count = count +1
    print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number) + ' individuals')

print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')
```

**UPDATE:**

And some minor code style improvements code be applied if you don't mind:

**UPDATE #2:**

I fixed only the loop, but as @Alan pointed out in the comments you calculate the loss wrong. Percent should be `1 - int(percent) * 0.01`

```
number = input('Number of individuals: ')  # tells the number of individuals in the beggining
number = int(number)
percent = input('% of loss per generation ')  # % of individuals lost in each generation
percent = 1 - int(percent) * 0.01

count = 0 # tells the nuumber of generations
while number >= 2:
    number = number * percent
    count += 1
    print('generation {}: {} individuals'.format(count, round(number)))    

print(' it took {} generations to end with the species.'.format(count))
```

Try the code https://repl.it/NWi4/2

**UPDATE #3:**

I've modified the code blocks to improve the rounding. It was `round(number, -1)`, which led to rounding of tens.

Comment: Your code is way batter than mine and you did really put a lot of effort here, but when I run it, it just keeps looping forever at one value. Any way we can solve this?

Comment: Yeah, right. It's because of rounding. We round fore example 40.88 back to 41 and the code keeps going. One moment.

Comment: I've fixed it. Take a look at the code in Update #2.

Comment: I've already tried it but several ''generations'' output the same number and in the end I have several generations with 0 individuals. For example if there are 100 individuals with 12% of losses this happens.

Comment: I mean I've adjusted it right now. 10 minutes ago. Try the new code once again please.

Comment: I did wait for a couple of minutes so it updated, but if you try the example I gave you it does the same thing.

Comment: Hm. It works for me with the example you provided. Have you noticed what was changed?     `number = number * percent` and `print('generation {}: {} individuals'.format(count, round(number, -1)))`

Comment: Yes I did noticed, and with the link that you gave me, if you input 100 and 12%, in my opinion if we are loosing 12% a generation, we should not have several generations with the same number of individuals.

Comment: Wow. Good point. I've just copied `round(number, -1)` and didn't noticed, that it's actually wrong. It should be `round(number)`. Because of -1 number will be rounded from 101 to 100 :) I'll fix it.

Comment: It did fixed the problem, but why does it repeat the 1 individuals? At the first time it shows 1, it should print the other sentence.

Comment: Because it's 1.x, which is greater as 1. I can adjust it also.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

```
number = input('Number of individuals: ')  # tells the number of individuals in the beggining
count = 0  # tells the nuumber of generations
number = int(number)
percent = input('% of loss per generation ')  # % of individuals lost in each generation
percent = int(percent)

while number > 1:
    number = number * (1 - percent * 0.01)
    number = int(number)
    count = count + 1
    print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number) + ' individuals')
print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')
```

Included @Alans suggestion.

The never ending loop problem happened because towards the end only a fraction less than 0.5 of an individual "died". With your `round(number, -1)` you rounded up  e.g. from 5 individuals 0.3 died so 4.7 remained but the rounding made them 5 again.  `int(number)` rounds down.

Comment: @losif Serafeimidis This made the code work as I was expecting and I did not found any errors when running it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you calculated number of alive snails wrong way, there should be (100% - loss %)*snails in every iteration snails left alive.
Second thing are conditions and round function. Your code is vurnelable to being stuck at point where loss is not enough to make the previous number lower after rounding, eg. 4 * 0.88 = 3.52, which after rounding is 4 again. So you can resign from rounding or use floor instead, depending on problem's nature. Question is how do we treat 0.52 of a snail?

For 12% loss and 100 individuals it took 37 generations to end with the species without rounding, and it took 24 generations to end with the species when using floor.

**Code below should work.**

```
import numpy as np
while True:
        if number <= 1: # <= covers values below 1
            print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')
            break;
        if number > 1:
            number = number*(1-percent*0.01) # number left is 1 - minus loss percent
            # number = np.floor(number) # optional floor
            count = count + 1
            # print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number*0.1) + ' individuals')
```

Comment: To work with this I have to download numpy right? I was looking for an easier way to solve without having to import other things.

Answer (score 0):

You code has two issues :

1. Wrong rounding - You are trying to round with negative value like -2. You need to use positive number while rounding.
2. Reducing number with each iteration

```
number = number - number*percent*0.01
```

Just change above two things in your code.

**Code after changes :**

```
number= input('Number of individuals: ')  #tells the number of individuals in the beggining
count = 0 #tells the nuumber of generations
number=int(number)
percent=input('% of loss per generation ')  #% of individuals lost in each generation
percent=int(percent)

while True:
    if number <= 1:
        print(' it took ' + str(count) + ' generations to end with the species')
        break
    if number > 1:
        number = number - number*percent*0.01
        number = round(number,2)

        count = count +1
        print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number*0.1) + ' individuals')
        print "Number is ",number
    if number == 0 :
        break
```

**Output:**

```
Number of individuals: "10"
% of loss per generation "2"
generation 1:0.98 individuals
Number is  9.8
generation 2:0.96 individuals
Number is  9.6
generation 3:0.941 individuals
Number is  9.41
generation 4:0.922 individuals
Number is  9.22
generation 5:0.904 individuals
Number is  9.04
generation 6:0.886 individuals
Number is  8.86
generation 7:0.868 individuals
Number is  8.68
generation 8:0.851 individuals
Number is  8.51
generation 9:0.834 individuals
Number is  8.34
generation 10:0.817 individuals
Number is  8.17
generation 11:0.801 individuals
Number is  8.01
generation 12:0.785 individuals
Number is  7.85
generation 13:0.769 individuals
Number is  7.69
generation 14:0.754 individuals
Number is  7.54
generation 15:0.739 individuals
Number is  7.39
generation 16:0.724 individuals
Number is  7.24
generation 17:0.71 individuals
Number is  7.1
generation 18:0.696 individuals
Number is  6.96
generation 19:0.682 individuals
Number is  6.82
generation 20:0.668 individuals
Number is  6.68
generation 21:0.655 individuals
Number is  6.55
generation 22:0.642 individuals
Number is  6.42
generation 23:0.629 individuals
Number is  6.29
generation 24:0.616 individuals
Number is  6.16
generation 25:0.604 individuals
Number is  6.04
generation 26:0.592 individuals
Number is  5.92
generation 27:0.58 individuals
Number is  5.8
generation 28:0.568 individuals
Number is  5.68
generation 29:0.557 individuals
Number is  5.57
generation 30:0.546 individuals
Number is  5.46
generation 31:0.535 individuals
Number is  5.35
generation 32:0.524 individuals
Number is  5.24
generation 33:0.514 individuals
Number is  5.14
generation 34:0.504 individuals
Number is  5.04
generation 35:0.494 individuals
Number is  4.94
generation 36:0.484 individuals
Number is  4.84
generation 37:0.474 individuals
Number is  4.74
generation 38:0.465 individuals
Number is  4.65
generation 39:0.456 individuals
Number is  4.56
generation 40:0.447 individuals
Number is  4.47
generation 41:0.438 individuals
Number is  4.38
generation 42:0.429 individuals
Number is  4.29
generation 43:0.42 individuals
Number is  4.2
generation 44:0.412 individuals
Number is  4.12
generation 45:0.404 individuals
Number is  4.04
generation 46:0.396 individuals
Number is  3.96
generation 47:0.388 individuals
Number is  3.88
generation 48:0.38 individuals
Number is  3.8
generation 49:0.372 individuals
Number is  3.72
generation 50:0.365 individuals
Number is  3.65
generation 51:0.358 individuals
Number is  3.58
generation 52:0.351 individuals
Number is  3.51
generation 53:0.344 individuals
Number is  3.44
generation 54:0.337 individuals
Number is  3.37
generation 55:0.33 individuals
Number is  3.3
generation 56:0.323 individuals
Number is  3.23
generation 57:0.317 individuals
Number is  3.17
generation 58:0.311 individuals
Number is  3.11
generation 59:0.305 individuals
Number is  3.05
generation 60:0.299 individuals
Number is  2.99
generation 61:0.293 individuals
Number is  2.93
generation 62:0.287 individuals
Number is  2.87
generation 63:0.281 individuals
Number is  2.81
generation 64:0.275 individuals
Number is  2.75
generation 65:0.269 individuals
Number is  2.69
generation 66:0.264 individuals
Number is  2.64
generation 67:0.259 individuals
Number is  2.59
generation 68:0.254 individuals
Number is  2.54
generation 69:0.249 individuals
Number is  2.49
generation 70:0.244 individuals
Number is  2.44
generation 71:0.239 individuals
Number is  2.39
generation 72:0.234 individuals
Number is  2.34
generation 73:0.229 individuals
Number is  2.29
generation 74:0.224 individuals
Number is  2.24
generation 75:0.22 individuals
Number is  2.2
generation 76:0.216 individuals
Number is  2.16
generation 77:0.212 individuals
Number is  2.12
generation 78:0.208 individuals
Number is  2.08
generation 79:0.204 individuals
Number is  2.04
generation 80:0.2 individuals
Number is  2.0
generation 81:0.196 individuals
Number is  1.96
generation 82:0.192 individuals
Number is  1.92
generation 83:0.188 individuals
Number is  1.88
generation 84:0.184 individuals
Number is  1.84
generation 85:0.18 individuals
Number is  1.8
generation 86:0.176 individuals
Number is  1.76
generation 87:0.172 individuals
Number is  1.72
generation 88:0.169 individuals
Number is  1.69
generation 89:0.166 individuals
Number is  1.66
generation 90:0.163 individuals
Number is  1.63
generation 91:0.16 individuals
Number is  1.6
generation 92:0.157 individuals
Number is  1.57
generation 93:0.154 individuals
Number is  1.54
generation 94:0.151 individuals
Number is  1.51
generation 95:0.148 individuals
Number is  1.48
generation 96:0.145 individuals
Number is  1.45
generation 97:0.142 individuals
Number is  1.42
generation 98:0.139 individuals
Number is  1.39
generation 99:0.136 individuals
Number is  1.36
generation 100:0.133 individuals
Number is  1.33
generation 101:0.13 individuals
Number is  1.3
generation 102:0.127 individuals
Number is  1.27
generation 103:0.124 individuals
Number is  1.24
generation 104:0.122 individuals
Number is  1.22
generation 105:0.12 individuals
Number is  1.2
generation 106:0.118 individuals
Number is  1.18
generation 107:0.116 individuals
Number is  1.16
generation 108:0.114 individuals
Number is  1.14
generation 109:0.112 individuals
Number is  1.12
generation 110:0.11 individuals
Number is  1.1
generation 111:0.108 individuals
Number is  1.08
generation 112:0.106 individuals
Number is  1.06
generation 113:0.104 individuals
Number is  1.04
generation 114:0.102 individuals
Number is  1.02
generation 115:0.1 individuals
Number is  1.0
 it took 115 generations to end with the species
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Iosif Serafeimidis's answer, this would keep reducing the population until the amount of the reduction is less than one. As others have said the answer really depends on what you want to express. NB that round(number) will round to the nearest integer, unlike int(number), which rounds to the next-lowest integer. Here is the modified version:

```
number = input('Number of individuals: ')  # tells the number of individuals in the beginning
count = 0  # tells the nuumber of generations
number = int(number)
percent = input('% of loss per generation ')  # % of individuals lost in each generation
percent = int(percent)

while number > 1:
    reduction = number * (percent * 0.01)
    if reduction < 1:
        print('No further reductions possible')
        break
    number = round(number - reduction)
    count = count + 1
    print('generation ' + str(count) + ':' + str(number) + ' individuals')

print(' after ' + str(count) + ' generations, there were ' + str(number) + ' individuals')
```